# How to set font size and font family at the same p

Tags: html, css, fonts, font-face, font-size

Can you give me a sample code on how to make a paragraph/text with text size and font, I only know the code that uses different sizes without font, and the code with the font but without resizing, here is my code: 
`<p style="font-family:arcade classic", "font-size:40px">Use the arrow keys (on your keyboard) to move your frog, avoid cars, jump on logs (flowing on the water), and jump on turtles (note that every few seconds, they swim underwater, then go back on the water's surface again, if you are on top of that turtle and it sinks, you die)</p>`

Comment: do you want to use inline CSS style for paragraphs?

Answer (score 1):

use CSS like

```
p{font-family:"poppins", sans-serif; font-size:2em;}
```

> /* do not forget to import Poppins from google font */

Comment: I think the user is free to choose the font :).

Answer (score 0):

You must use one single string in your style attribute

```
<p style="font-family:arcade classic; font-size:40px"></p>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I don't think citation means what you think it means.

Answer (score 0):

You had a syntax problem.  You should have used a semicolon where you used a comma as @farshid-mousavi said.